# Clearing NumericUpDown

Tags: vb.net, winforms, numericupdown

My problem with NumericUpDown control is when the user selects a value from NumericUpDown And unchecks the checkBox1 and clicks the Save button, the value of NumericUpDown not cleared:

```
 Public Class FormAdd


Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.StudenttableBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub BttnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BttnSave.Click

    Me.StudenttableBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.StudenttableTableAdapter.Update(Me.StudentDataSet.studenttable)
    Me.StudenttableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StudentDataSet.studenttable)
    MsgBox(" Student Saveed", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Me.StudenttableTableAdapter.Fill(Main.StudentDataSet.studenttable)
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        AgeNumericUpDown.Value = AgeNumericUpDown.Minimum
        AgeNumericUpDown.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

I need if the user selects a value and unchecks the CheckBox1 value of AgeNumericUpDown to reset to an empty string.

Illustrated:

[image]

Comment: Previously you said you want the value to be empty when click on save button, and your code is showing you want the value to be empty when checkbox's check is changed!?

Comment: The AgeNumericUpDown Valeu empty when Uncheck Checkbox .Its Ok ..The Problem Is When I Click Save Butten The  AgeNumericUpDown Databinding Get The Value Before empty

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with the NumericUpDown control.  Try re-wording your question to focus on the DataGridView problem you are trying to solve. Oh, and also, please don't capitalize the first letter of every word in your sentences.

Comment: Nothing is updating any tables after `CheckBox1_CheckedChanged` you are just loading up the same data and not making any edit other than changing the value in the `NumericUpDown`

Answer (score 0):

NumericUpDown does not contain string. It has value as numbers. So it should be:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
      If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            AgeNumericUpDown.Value = 0
      End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Check this out then if you don't want the value to be zero, but empty!

```
 Private Sub BttnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BttnSave.Click
    If AgeNumericUpDown.Value <> 0 Then
        AgeNumericUpDown.Controls(1).Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks For Replay But I Dont Need Value To Be "0" I Want  It  Empty

Comment: I have edited my answer. Hope you would be able cope your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Access the text control of the `NumericUpDown` and then set text to be blank

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged

    If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
        AgeNumericUpDown.Controls.Item(1).Text = ""
    End If

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks For Replay But Its Not Working .. Example I Select 15 And Uncheck CheckBox1 and Click Save .. I found The Age Coulmn On Datagridview = 15

Comment: If you are using `Checkbox`s from a `DatagridView` then you need to fire an `CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged` event. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged.aspx

Comment: I Know When I Uncheck CheckBox1 The AgeNumericUpDown Value IS Deleted But The Problem Is When Click Save The Coulm Age In Datagridview Show The selected Value  Example I Select 15 And Uncheck CheckBox1 and Click Save .. I found The Age Coulmn On Datagridview = 15

Comment: I don't understand. You are not sending any information to the `DataGridView` after the `CheckBox` changed so how is the  `DataGridView` going to change

Answer (score 0):

I was using the NumericUpDown control without the spinners because I wanted only numbers. The control was in a child dialog that was invoked from a listview selection. When the value to be loaded into the NumericUpDown control was zero in the listwiew, a zero was in the control. That zero always had to be cleared out. Here's how I made it "appear" blank. If it was zero, I change the ForeColor of the control to white. I added an Enter event that changed the ForeColor to black and deleted the zero.

This hid the NumericUpDown control spinners.

```
AccessCode.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

These statements were in the form initialization. (var code was to be loaded into AccessCode)

```
        if (code == 0)
        {
            AccessCode.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
```

The Enter event code looked like this.

```
    private void AccessCode_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (AccessCode.ForeColor == Color.White)
        {
            AccessCode.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            AccessCode.Focus();
            SendKeys.SendWait("{Delete}");
        }
    }
```

The AccessCode control also had a Leave event that checked for valid data.